# Regular expression <(.*?)> returning < or >

Tags: c, regex

I am attempting to run a regular expression to pull a string of any characters from a file that is contained between "<" and ">".  The regex that I have come up with is

```
[ <(.*?)>]
```

However, when I run this regex using fscanf I only get a "<" or ">" as my output for anything contained within the signs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int next_word(FILE* filename,char word[254])
{
    if (fscanf(filename, "%254[<(.*?)>]", word) == 1)
    {
        printf("%s\n",word);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (fscanf(filename, "%[^a-zA-Z]", word) == 1) { return 1; }
    else if (fscanf(filename, "%254[a-zA-Z]", word) == 1) {return 1; }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char word[254];
    FILE *infile;

    infile = fopen(argv[2],"r");
    while(1)
    {
        if(next_word(infile,word) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My input file is as follows:

```
<test> this is a line <end>
```

Which gives the output:

```
<
>

 <
>
```

but should give

```
<test>
<end>
```

Comment: The scanf functions don't use regular expressions...

Comment: Also you have a potential buffer overflow from telling fscanf to read up to 254 characters into a 64 character long array.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, I'll fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the format string of scanf family are not regex, and I don't think that your regex will work (you can use online regex testing).

You can try

```
fscanf(filename, "<%254[^>]>", word) == 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a good way to make sure that "<" and ">" also get written to the storage element, instead of just the string?

Comment: Well, not really because scanf are not regex, so you can't "capture".

Comment: Nevermind, it doesn't matter for this application anyway.  I confused myself.  See username.  Thanks for the help.